# Can capacitors amplify signals?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, voltage-amplification

While reading a topic on opamps, I came across this topic. It said, other devices like capacitors amplify signals differently for different frequencies, while opamps amplify signals irrespective of the frequency (sustained gain.)

I haven't heard of amplification using capacitors. I wish to know how does it do and can we find the frequency response of amplification using capacitors?

Comment: Sounds more like a poorly written text.  Capacitors have an impedance that varies by frequency.  This leads to being able to reduce the signal depending on frequency.  That is generally called attenuation.

Comment: Opamps have a gain function that strongly depends on frequency. You should clearly distinguish between parts (opamp) and circuits (opamp based amplifiers with feedback).

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDsoWb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The shown - purely passive - RC-circuit has a **gain larger than unity** at an angular frequency of w=1000 rad/s. However, the gain is only slightly above unity (app. Vout/V1=1.06).
Such a circuit can be - and is - used in RC oscillators using unity gain amplifiers.

Comment: I wouldn`t say that in the circuit we have "amplification by capacitors". Rather, we have a kind of signal enhancement caused by superposition based on different phase shift effects,

Answer (score 3):

> I havent heard of amplification using capacitors. wish to know how
>   does it do and can we find the frequency response of amplification
>   using capacitors

It depends on your definition of "amplifier". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier) defines it like this: -

> An amplifier, electronic amplifier or (informally) amp is an
>   electronic device that can increase the power of a signal (a
>   time-varying voltage or current). It is a two-port electronic circuit
>   that uses electric power from a power supply to increase the amplitude
>   of a signal applied to its input terminals, producing a proportionally
>   greater amplitude signal at its output. The amount of amplification
>   provided by an amplifier is measured by its gain: the ratio of output
>   voltage, current, or power to input. An amplifier is a circuit that
>   has a power gain greater than one.

It is unambiguous in stating that the power gain is greater than 1 but this is just one definition. If you took a definition of an amplifier as a device that increased the voltage of a signal then you could argue that a transformer is an amplifier. You could also argue that an RLC filter was also an amplifier because it can provide significant voltage gain such as in this tuned circuit: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html).

At resonance the voltage amplification is 20 dB or a gain of 10. There is of course no power gain because there is no "extra" power source that can provide power.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor is a passive component, so it can't amplify. Full stop.

That text isn't good. What it *probably meant to say* is that, using capacitors, you can build frequency-selective circuits (for example, an R-C low pass filter). And what it meant to say was maybe that Opamps can be used in configurations that are not frequency-selective (within the limits of the opamp).

All in all, get a better textbook.

Comment: Just substitute "attenuate" for amplify in the original quote, and it's sorta accurate.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal capacitor, no it is not possible, however:

I believe it is possible (though probably not particularly useful) to get power gain from a ceramic capacitor due to the voltage-capacitance nonlinearity. Pump it with double the frequency of your signal and use it as a parametric amplifier.